# Usando ponteiro de ponteiro em C

Tags: c

olá

estou fazendo um trabalho de algoritmos em C e parei em uma parte.
O programa tem que ler de um arquivo de entrada e inserir em uma árvore Trie n-ária.

O código que le do arquivo é esse:

```
int abre_arquivo(TRIE_N ** root) {

  FILE* arquivo;

  char* word;

  arquivo = fopen("dicionario.txt", "r");

  if (arquivo == NULL)

    printf("Arquivo não pode ser aberto.\n");

  else {

    while ((fscanf(arquivo, "%s\n", word)) != EOF) {

      insertTrie(&(*root), word);

    }

  }

  fclose(arquivo);

  return 0;

}
```

o cabeçalho da função insertTrie é:

```
int insertTrie(TRIE_N ** root, char * word)
```

Queria saber como chamar a função **insertTrie** dentro da **abre_arquivo** corretamente.
Usei o gdb e está dando falha de segmentação na linha

```
current = &(*root)->children[word[0]-97];
```

da insertTrie. 
Se tiver mais algum erro na função gostaria de saber tambem.

Obrigada

Comment: `root` não mudou em `abre_arquivo`, simplesmente passou para `insertTrie`. (Mas por que escrever `&(*root)` em `abre_arquivo` quando pode escrever `root`?) Parece-me que seria mais importante demonstrar qual é valor que passou a `abre_arquivo`, e o conteúdo de `insertTrie`.

Comment: Você não esta alocando o seu ponteiro `word`, quando tenta inserir valor ou escrever o que tem dentro, não encontra nada e da erro de memória.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer

```
char word[50];
```

e na chamada da função faça

```
insertTrie(root, word);
```

acho que isso resolve seu problema.